# SSRS darasource

Tags: sql-server, database, reporting-services, datasource

I am trying to find the datasource of an SSRS report

I go to Properties and Data Sources then I see a bath in "A shared data source" (which was ticked)

"/Dynamics/Reports/Data Sources/dsJobReporting"

when I click on Browse next to it there is no such data source,
I reopened the folders but could not find any data source in there.

The "A custom data source" is not ticked, so it is disabled.

The report shows data when I click on "View Report"

but I dont know what is the source of that report!.

Is there any other way I can search for the data source?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you just have no permissions on datasources. Try to navigate to /Dynamics/Reports/Data Sources/ in another browser window and if you don't see nothing it means you have no permissions

Comment: You could run a trace on the server (SQL Server Profiler) and see what queries are executed when you run the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the  /Dynamics/Reports/Data Sources/ folder was hidden and the only way to access that not through the browse button.
I have to go to that folder through SSRS interface website.